# SSIS zip a file using 7zip

Tags: ssis, 7zip

I am using ssis to zip and rename  a folder with about 7 files in it. when it zips the folder and renames it the old folder is inside of the zip folder i would just like to have the zip folder with the new name and the files inside of that.
i have tried

```
    a -tzip "F:\Extracts\QCExtracts\QCreports_2014_07.zip" "F:\Extracts\QCExtracts\QCreports\"

     a -tzip "F:\Extracts\QCExtracts\QCreports_2014_07.zip" "F:\Extracts\QCExtracts\QCreports"
```

for both i get the result of `QCreports_2014_07.zip\ QCreports\all files`

i need it to be `QCreports_2014_07.zip\ all files`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use "Execute Process Task" for the 7z.exe call:

You have to set `F:\Extracts\QCExtracts\QCreports\`as `WorkingDirectory` in the Process section of your Task. This should omit the subdirectory in the zip file.